# ngrok ERROR: Tunnel 'command_line' specifies an invalid or malformed address

Tags: command-line, localhost, port, ngrok

I am currently running a local webpage on port 8080 like so `localhost:8080/viewer/`

I want to quickly share the webpage with a co-worker, so I downloaded `ngrok`

Whilst I can set up a link for 8080 by using the command `ngrok http 8080` - this is not the correct page being displayed. I need `ngrok http 8000/viewer/` but when I try that I get `ERROR:  Tunnel 'command_line' specifies an invalid or malformed address '8080/viewer/': strange hostname`

How can I overcome this to display the correct page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PM from ngrok here. The path to your app (/viewer/) needs to be appended to the url that ngrok provides after you start. You have the correct command: `ngrok http 8080` but you will need to take the url that ngrok creates and append `/viewer/` to it, so that it looks like this: `https://<hash>.ngrok-free.app/viewer/`.